# Can't use of Font class in my App

Tags: android

I want use of Font class in my Android app,I add JRE system Library in my project(every thing is ok),but when I run,in log cat show this Error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.awt.Font

Comment: How to used it? Where is your  code?

Comment: It's My code:Font font=new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12);

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use AWT in Android.

The correct way to use a custom font is to instantiate a `Typeface`.
For example:

```
Typeface customTypeface = Typeface.createFromFile(assets, "fonts/CustomFont.ttf");
myTextView.setTypeface(customTypeface);
```

[Typeface.createFromFile(AssetManager, String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html#createFromAsset%28android.content.res.AssetManager,%20java.lang.String%29)

You can also use a third party library like [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) to do the dirty work for you. This even allows you to set the typeface from your xml layouts and styles